# Problema con lista de opciones con string-array en Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

Estoy creando una lista de opciones mi problema es cuando selecciono y después quiero de seleccionar esa misma opción. Me marca error en esta parte:

```
mMercado.remove(position);
```

Código de Strings:

```
<string-array name="mercado">
        <item>Nacional</item>
        <item>EEUU</item>
        <item>Canada</item>
        <item>Europa</item>
        <item>Japon</item>
        <item>Organico</item>
        <item>Limpio</item>
        <item>SemíLimpio</item>
        <item>2daClase</item>
        <item>China</item>
        <item>Mendez</item>
        <item>Aventajado</item>
        <item>Bandeado</item>
    </string-array>
```

Código del botón que lanza la lista:

```
bmercado =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMercado);
    bmercado.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cortes_Registro.this);
            mBuilder.setTitle("Seleccionar Mercado");
            mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(listMercado, checkMercado, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked){
                        if (! mMercado.contains(position)){
                            mMercado.add(position);
                        }
                    }else if (mMercado.contains(position)){
                        mMercado.remove(position);
                        //Aqui me marca error!!! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    }
                }
            });

            mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String item = "";
                    for (int i=0; i< mMercado.size(); i++){
                        item = item+listMercado[mMercado.get(i)];
                        if (i != mMercado.size() -1){
                            item = item + ",";
                        }
                    }
                    infoMercado.setText(item);
                }
            });

            mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cerrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            mBuilder.setNeutralButton("Limpiar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                for (int i = 0; i<checkMercado.length;i++){
                    checkMercado[i] = false;
                    mMercado.clear();
                    infoMercado.setText("Seleccionar Mercado");
                }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil, PID: 5123
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 1 at
>   java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477) at
>   desarrolladoresalpha.hassmovil.Cortes_Confirmar$4$1.onClick(‌​Cortes_Confirmar.jav‌​a:94)

Comment: Podrías poner la excepción que te está dando?

Comment: No se que es mMarcado ni que tiene dentro, pero al parecer son los items marcados, para borrarlo, simplemente busca el elemento dentro del array que contiene dentro de los campos y recorre el array de seleccionados en busca de ese elemento y lo quitas

Comment: A. ¿Puedes mostrar el código donde incluyes la variable `mMercado`? Es lo que está dando problemas. ¿La has incluido correctamente? B. Cuando algo te de error, escribe qué error está dando en la pregunta. No todo el log del error, sino unas cuantas líneas antes y después de donde dice: `Caused by ...`

Comment: @ManuelMorales Ya hizo caso del comentario y puso, menos mal, el código de error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que estas intentando eliminar el elemento 4 cuando solo tienes 1 elemento:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 1
```

El problema viene cuando haces el `mMercado.remove(position)` ya que intuyo que lo que quieres hacer es borrar el objeto position y no el objeto que contiene la lista en la posición `position`. Para conseguir lo que necesitas, tienes que buscar la posición del objeto y luego borrarla con el remove:

```
int pos = mMercado.indexOf(position);
mMercado.remove(pos);
```

Comment: excelente me funciono.

Answer (score -1):

Estas eliminando un elemento en el indice 4 (`position`) cuando el tamaño de todo el `ArrayList` es de solo un elemento:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 1 at
>   java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:477)

Tienes que realizar una validación, permitiendo eliminar el elemento en la posición definida, únicamente si el tamaño del ArrayList es mayor que `position` (`position` es un indice inicia en 0):

```
 if(mMercado.size() > position){
       mMercado.remove(position);
 }
```

---

Sugiero revises tu código ya que no veo porque razón buscarías si en el ArrayList contienes un entero, y en base a esto remover la posición relacionada a ese entero:

```
                else if (mMercado.contains(position)){
                    mMercado.remove(position);
                    //Aqui me marca error!!! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                }
```

Regularmente se busca un elemento dentro del ArrayList y se elimina/agrega:

```
 if (mMercado.contains(mMercado.get(position))){ // Busca en el ArrayList un elemento, para eliminarlo.
     mMercado.remove(position);
 }
```

**Nunca va a ser mayor el valor de la variable `position` ya que esta relacionada a la cantidad de elementos en la UI, es importante tomar en cuenta que el valor inicial de `position` en el primer elemento es 0 ya que es un indice.**